# CF8 and AES decrypting MySQL AES: encodings are not same

Tags: mysql, encryption, coldfusion, aes, coldfusion-8

This has become more of an exercise in what am I doing wrong than mission critical, but I'd still like to see what (simple probably) mistake I'm making.

I'm using mysql (5.1.x) AES_ENCRYPT to encrypt a string.  I'm using CF's generateSecretKey('AES') to make a key (I've tried it at defaul and 128 and 256 bit lengths).

So let's say my code looks like this:

```
    <cfset key = 'qLHVTZL9zF81kiTnNnK0Vg=='/>
    <cfset strToEncrypt = '4111111111111111'/>
    <cfquery name="i" datasource="#dsn#">
        INSERT INTO table(str) 
            VALUES AES_ENCRYPT(strToEncrypt,'#key#');
    </cfquery>
```

That works fine as expected and I can select it using SELECT AES_DECRYPT(str,'#key#') AS... with no problems at all.

What I can't seem to do though is get CF to decrypt it using something like:

```
    <cfquery name="s" datasource="#dsn#">
        SELECT str
          FROM table
    </cfquery>
    <cfoutput>#Decrypt(s.str,key,'AES')#</cfoutput>
```

or

```
    <cfoutput>#Decrypt(toString(s.str),key,'AES')#</cfoutput>
```

I keep getting "The input and output encodings are not same" (including the toString() - without that I get a binary data error).  The field type for the encrypted string in the db is blob.

Comment: I've fixed a couple of tiny `cfml` things, but your queries look like you've written, but not really tested. This looks not very good. You should be more careful with code samples -- we may want to try them (surprise!).

Comment: These were definitely not real queries or anything - just used to illustrate the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[This entry](http://info.michael-simons.eu/2011/07/18/mysql-compatible-aes-encryption-decryption-in-java/) explains that mySQL handles AES-128 keys a bit differently than you might expect:

> .. the MySQL algorithm just or’s the bytes of a given passphrase
>   against the previous bytes if the password is longer than 16 chars and
>   just leaves them 0 when the password is shorter than 16 chars.

Not highly tested, but this seems to yield the same results (in hex).

```
<cfscript>
    function getMySQLAES128Key( key ) {
        var keyBytes   = charsetDecode( arguments.key, "utf-8" );
        var finalBytes = listToArray( repeatString("0,", 16) );

        for (var i = 1; i <= arrayLen(keyBytes); i++) {
            // adjust for base 0 vs 1 index
            var pos = ((i-1) % 16) + 1;
            finalBytes[ pos ] = bitXOR(finalBytes[ pos ], keyBytes[ i ]);
        }

        return binaryEncode( javacast("byte[]", finalBytes ), "base64" );
    }

    key     = "qLHVTZL9zF81kiTnNnK0Vg==";
    input   = "4111111111111111";

    encrypted = encrypt(input, getMySQLAES128Key(key), "AES", "hex");
    WriteDump("encrypted="& encrypted);

    // note: assumes input is in "hex". either convert the bytes 
    // to hex in mySQL first or use binaryEncode
    decrypted = decrypt(encrypted, getMySQLAES128Key(key), "AES", "hex");
    WriteDump("decrypted="& decrypted);
</cfscript>
```

**Note:** If you are using mySQL for encryption be sure to see its documentation which mentions [the plain text may end up in various logs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/encryption-functions.html)  (replication, history, etectera) and "may be read by anyone having read access to that information".

---

**Update:** Things may have changed, but according to [this 2004 bug report](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=3172) the `.mysql_history` file is only on Unix. (Keep in mind there may be other log files) Detailed instructions for clearing .mysql_history can be [found in the manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-history-file.html), but in summary:

> - Set the `MYSQL_HISTFILE` variable to /dev/null (on each log in)
> - Create .mysql_history as a symbolic link to /dev/null (only once)

Comment: Yeah, I was a little surprised when I saw that in the documentation. Definitely something I would not have thought of..

Comment: Great tip on the logs.  I ended up rolling my own in that CF encrypts the initial string and MySQL encrypts the CF key.  I do want to go through my MySQL logs though and see what's being logged and if/how to move or change the logging settings.

Comment: @Steve - If you find out anything new about the log settings, do post it. I would be curious to know if there is a way to disable it / or if the behavior has changed in recent versions.